# Time Machine logging in 10.6

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, time-machine

I would like to know if Time Machine log entries have changed in 10.6.x. To answer this would someone who uses Time Machine and is on 10.6 run this command and paste the results?

> syslog | grep backupd | tail -n 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the Time Machine Logging has not changed in any significant manner between 10.5 & 10.6...

Updated with Terminal Syslog...

```
[nerv:~] benjamin% syslog | grep backupd | tail -n 10
Sat Nov 21 16:58:13 nerv com.apple.backupd[799] <Notice>: Copied 1553 files (69 KB) from volume Nerv_Central_Control.
Sat Nov 21 16:58:13 nerv com.apple.backupd[799] <Notice>: Copied 1556 files (69 KB) from volume 1tb-storage.
Sat Nov 21 16:58:14 nerv com.apple.backupd[799] <Notice>: Copied 2014 files (69 KB) from volume DVR Storage.
Sat Nov 21 16:58:14 nerv com.apple.backupd[799] <Notice>: Copied 2051 files (69 KB) from volume Disk2.
Sat Nov 21 16:58:19 nerv com.apple.backupd[799] <Notice>: Starting post-backup thinning
Sat Nov 21 16:58:31 nerv com.apple.backupd[799] <Notice>: Deleted backup /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/nerv/2009-11-20-163212: 129.02 GB now available
Sat Nov 21 16:58:40 nerv com.apple.backupd[799] <Notice>: Deleted backup /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/nerv/2009-11-20-153211: 129.05 GB now available
Sat Nov 21 16:59:35 nerv com.apple.backupd[799] <Notice>: Deleted backup /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/nerv/2009-11-20-143207: 129.10 GB now available
Sat Nov 21 16:59:35 nerv com.apple.backupd[799] <Notice>: Post-back up thinning complete: 3 expired backups removed
Sat Nov 21 16:59:36 nerv com.apple.backupd[799] <Notice>: Backup completed successfully.
11/20/09 1:31:06 AM com.apple.backupd[2101] Starting standard backup
11/20/09 1:31:06 AM com.apple.backupd[2101] Backing up to: /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb
11/20/09 1:31:17 AM com.apple.backupd[2101] No pre-backup thinning needed: 246.7 MB requested (including padding), 129.33 GB available
11/20/09 1:31:29 AM com.apple.backupd[2101] Copied 3528 files (3.5 MB) from volume Nerv_Central_Control.
11/20/09 1:31:30 AM com.apple.backupd[2101] Copied 3531 files (3.5 MB) from volume 1tb-storage.
11/20/09 1:31:33 AM com.apple.backupd[2101] Copied 3989 files (3.5 MB) from volume DVR Storage.
11/20/09 1:31:34 AM com.apple.backupd[2101] Copied 4026 files (3.5 MB) from volume Disk2.
11/20/09 1:31:35 AM com.apple.backupd[2101] No pre-backup thinning needed: 242.6 MB requested (including padding), 129.33 GB available
11/20/09 1:31:36 AM com.apple.backupd[2101] Copied 210 files (97 bytes) from volume Nerv_Central_Control.
11/20/09 1:31:36 AM com.apple.backupd[2101] Copied 213 files (97 bytes) from volume 1tb-storage.
11/20/09 1:31:37 AM com.apple.backupd[2101] Copied 671 files (97 bytes) from volume DVR Storage.
11/20/09 1:31:38 AM com.apple.backupd[2101] Copied 708 files (97 bytes) from volume Disk2.
11/20/09 1:31:40 AM com.apple.backupd[2101] Starting post-backup thinning
11/20/09 1:31:40 AM com.apple.backupd[2101] No post-back up thinning needed: no expired backups exist
11/20/09 1:31:40 AM com.apple.backupd[2101] Backup completed successfully.

11/19/09 10:31:06 PM    com.apple.backupd[1552] Starting standard backup
11/19/09 10:31:07 PM    com.apple.backupd[1552] Backing up to: /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb
11/19/09 10:32:06 PM    com.apple.backupd[1552] No pre-backup thinning needed: 260.6 MB requested (including padding), 129.30 GB available
11/19/09 10:33:07 PM    com.apple.backupd[1552] Copied 12551 files (15.1 MB) from volume Nerv_Central_Control.
11/19/09 10:33:09 PM    com.apple.backupd[1552] Copied 12554 files (15.1 MB) from volume 1tb-storage.
11/19/09 10:33:14 PM    com.apple.backupd[1552] Copied 13012 files (15.1 MB) from volume DVR Storage.
11/19/09 10:33:16 PM    com.apple.backupd[1552] Copied 13049 files (15.1 MB) from volume Disk2.
11/19/09 10:33:17 PM    com.apple.backupd[1552] No pre-backup thinning needed: 283.6 MB requested (including padding), 129.28 GB available
11/19/09 10:33:24 PM    com.apple.backupd[1552] Copied 1561 files (34.2 MB) from volume Nerv_Central_Control.
11/19/09 10:33:24 PM    com.apple.backupd[1552] Copied 1564 files (34.2 MB) from volume 1tb-storage.
11/19/09 10:33:25 PM    com.apple.backupd[1552] Copied 2022 files (34.2 MB) from volume DVR Storage.
11/19/09 10:33:25 PM    com.apple.backupd[1552] Copied 2059 files (34.2 MB) from volume Disk2.
11/19/09 10:33:30 PM    com.apple.backupd[1552] Starting post-backup thinning
11/19/09 10:34:04 PM    com.apple.backupd[1552] Deleted backup /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/nerv/2009-11-18-215423: 129.30 GB now available
11/19/09 10:34:04 PM    com.apple.backupd[1552] Post-back up thinning complete: 1 expired backups removed
11/19/09 10:34:04 PM    com.apple.backupd[1552] Backup completed successfully.
```

Comment: That looks like entries from Console.app, correct? Would you be able to post the result from the command line? I'm writing a script so I want to be sure of exactly how this is formatted.

Comment: Updated with Syslog...

Answer (score 0):

Here are some samples from mine.  The first is from console to give you some context, the latter two are syslog.

```
Nov 19 23:16:14 localhost com.apple.backupd[2344]: Starting standard backup
Nov 19 23:16:14 localhost com.apple.backupd[2344]: Backing up to: /Volumes/raidbackup/Backups.backupdb
Nov 19 23:16:15 localhost com.apple.backupd[2344]: 2009-11-19 23:16:15.086 FindSystemFiles[2345:907] Looking for system packages
Nov 19 23:16:15 localhost com.apple.backupd[2344]: 2009-11-19 23:16:15.390 FindSystemFiles[2345:907] PackageKit: *** Missing bundle identifier: /Library/Receipts/Flip4Mac QuickTime Components.pkg
Nov 19 23:16:15 localhost com.apple.backupd[2344]: 2009-11-19 23:16:15.395 FindSystemFiles[2345:907] PackageKit: *** Missing bundle identifier: /Library/Receipts/Flip4Mac Web Plugins.pkg
Nov 19 23:16:15 localhost com.apple.backupd[2344]: 2009-11-19 23:16:15.681 FindSystemFiles[2345:907] Using system path cache.
Nov 19 23:16:41 localhost com.apple.backupd[2344]: No pre-backup thinning needed: 249.4 MB requested (including padding), 32.80 GB available
Nov 19 23:16:41 localhost com.apple.backupd[2344]: Indexer unavailable (1)
```

...

```
Fri Nov 20 14:48:35 localhost com.apple.backupd-auto[10113] <Notice>: Not starting scheduled Time Machine backup - time machine destination not resolvable.
Fri Nov 20 17:12:47 localhost com.apple.backupd-auto[10974] <Notice>: Not starting scheduled Time Machine backup - time machine destination not resolvable.
Fri Nov 20 18:12:47 localhost com.apple.backupd-auto[11576] <Notice>: Not starting scheduled Time Machine backup - time machine destination not resolvable.
Fri Nov 20 19:12:47 localhost com.apple.backupd-auto[12000] <Notice>: Not starting scheduled Time Machine backup - time machine destination not resolvable.
Fri Nov 20 20:12:47 localhost com.apple.backupd-auto[12424] <Notice>: Not starting scheduled Time Machine backup - time machine destination not resolvable.
Fri Nov 20 21:12:46 localhost com.apple.backupd-auto[12850] <Notice>: Not starting scheduled Time Machine backup - time machine destination not resolvable.
Fri Nov 20 22:12:46 localhost com.apple.backupd-auto[13520] <Notice>: Not starting scheduled Time Machine backup - time machine destination not resolvable.
Fri Nov 20 23:12:46 localhost com.apple.backupd-auto[14312] <Notice>: Not starting scheduled Time Machine backup - time machine destination not resolvable.
Sat Nov 21 11:28:27 localhost com.apple.backupd-auto[951] <Notice>: Not starting scheduled Time Machine backup - time machine destination not resolvable.
Sat Nov 21 12:45:51 localhost com.apple.backupd-auto[1602] <Notice>: Not starting scheduled Time Machine backup - time machine destination not resolvable.
```

...

```
Sat Nov 21 16:25:18 localhost com.apple.backupd[2180] <Error>: Failed to write attrs for /Volumes/raidbackup/Backups.backupdb/localhost/2009-11-20-001620/Macintosh HD/Users/user/Library/Mail/IMAP-emailaddy/Trash.imapmbox/Messages/40200.emlx ({\n    "_kTimeMachineNewestSnapshot" = "2009-11-20 00:16:20 -0500";\n})
Sat Nov 21 16:25:18 localhost com.apple.backupd[2180] <Error>: Failed to write attrs for /Volumes/raidbackup/Backups.backupdb/localhost/2009-11-20-001620/Macintosh HD/Users/user/Library/Mail/IMAP-emailaddy/Trash.imapmbox/Messages/40205.emlx ({\n    "_kTimeMachineNewestSnapshot" = "2009-11-20 00:16:20 -0500";\n})
Sat Nov 21 16:25:18 localhost com.apple.backupd[2180] <Error>: Failed to write attrs for /Volumes/raidbackup/Backups.backupdb/localhost/2009-11-20-001620/Macintosh HD/Users/user/Library/Mail/IMAP-emailaddy/Trash.imapmbox/Messages/40207.emlx ({\n    "_kTimeMachineNewestSnapshot" = "2009-11-20 00:16:20 -0500";\n})
Sat Nov 21 16:25:30 localhost com.apple.backupd[2180] <Notice>: Copied 9094 files (281.2 MB) from volume Macintosh HD.
Sat Nov 21 16:25:31 localhost com.apple.backupd[2180] <Notice>: Starting post-backup thinning
Sat Nov 21 16:25:43 localhost com.apple.backupd[2180] <Notice>: Deleted backup /Volumes/raidbackup/Backups.backupdb/localhost/2009-10-22-221920: 37.38 GB now available
Sat Nov 21 16:25:43 localhost com.apple.backupd[2180] <Notice>: Post-back up thinning complete: 1 expired backups removed
Sat Nov 21 16:25:43 localhost com.apple.backupd[2180] <Notice>: Backup completed successfully.
```